# fatal error duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, duplicates

I've try to upload a database file to my server but am getting the following error message when importing. I've searched for other similar problems but can't work out how to fix this.

This is the message i get:

> Error at the line 61: (2, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, 'Site');

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `mage_S3CUr3_admin_role` (`role_id`, `parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `role_name`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators'),
(2, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, 'Site')
```

MySQL: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

This is the tablestructure, I hope somebody can help me out with this and give me a good code.

```
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `mage_S3CUr3_admin_role`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mage_S3CUr3_admin_role` (
  `role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Role ID',
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Parent Role ID',
  `tree_level` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Role Tree Level',
  `sort_order` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Role Sort Order',
  `role_type` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Role Type',
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'User ID',
  `role_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Role Name',
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`),
  KEY `IDX_OZSS_ADMIN_ROLE_PARENT_ID_SORT_ORDER` (`parent_id`,`sort_order`),
  KEY `IDX_OZSS_ADMIN_ROLE_TREE_LEVEL` (`tree_level`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Role Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `mage_S3CUr3_admin_role`
--
```

**EDIT**

I get this

```
Error at the line 81: ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Rule Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `mage_S3CUr3_admin_role`
(`parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `role_name`) VALUES
(0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, 'Site')
--
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mage_S3CUr3_admin_rule` (
`rule_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Rule ID',
`role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Role ID',
`resource_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Resource ID',
`privileges` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Privileges',
`assert_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Assert ID',
`role_type` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Role Type',
`permission` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Permission',
PRIMARY KEY (`rule_id`),
KEY `IDX_OZSS_ADMIN_RULE_RESOURCE_ID_ROLE_ID` (`resource_id`,`role_id`),
KEY `IDX_OZSS_ADMIN_RULE_ROLE_ID_RESOURCE_ID` (`role_id`,`resource_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Rule Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=2

MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mage_S3CUr3_admin_rule` ( `rule_id` int(10) unsign' at line 9
```

Comment: Simple, you're doing a manual insert (even for primary key) but you cannot use the same key (used before), you need to give a unique key each time.

Comment: If a column has `AUTO_INCREMENT` in it, it means also `automatic increment`!

Comment: can you change it for me? How I must set this?

Comment: Change INSERT INTO `mage_S3CUr3_admin_role` (`role_id`, `parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `role_name`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators'),
(2, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, 'Site') with something like: INSERT INTO `mage_S3CUr3_admin_role` (`parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `role_name`) VALUES
(0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, 'Site')

Answer (score 1):

Do not specify role_id - as it is an AUTO_INCREMENT field.

MySQL will supply a unique role_id for you.

You can use LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the value inserted into role_id by AUTO_INCREMENT. You can use that for your parent_id - assuming you want to get the value of role_id of the previous insert as the parent_id for the subsequent row. You will need to split out your inserts.

Have a look at a working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9755b/1/0

```
INSERT INTO `mage_S3CUr3_admin_role` 
(`parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `role_name`) 
VALUES
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators');

INSERT INTO `mage_S3CUr3_admin_role` 
(`parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `role_name`) 
VALUES
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 2, 0, 'U', 1, 'Site');
```

Have a look at a working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9755b/1/0

Answer (score 0):

I still get a error :(

Error at the line 94: (1, 1, 'all', NULL, 0, 'G', 'allow');

### Query: --

INSERT INTO `mage_S3CUr3_admin_rule` (`rule_id`, `role_id`, `resource_id`, `privileges`, `assert_id`, `role_type`, `permission`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'all', NULL, 0, 'G', 'allow')

MySQL: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

You can download it here and see it for yourself
anthonydeboer.nl/dump/Archive.zip